# Calculate the radicals

Tags: radicals

I want to calculate this expresion

$ \sqrt {1-2 \sqrt[3]{6} + \sqrt[3]{36}} $

And this expresion I want to simplify it

$ \frac {3 \sqrt{a}}{a} + a^{\frac{1}{6}} \sqrt[3]{a} - \frac{a^{\frac{2}{7}}}{\sqrt{a}} - \frac{3a^0}{\sqrt{a}} $ with a>0

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt[3]{36}=\sqrt[3]{6^2}=(\sqrt[3]6)^2$

So, $1-2\sqrt[3]6+\sqrt[3]{36}=1^2-2\cdot1\cdot\sqrt[3]6+(\sqrt[3]6)^2=?$

Comment: Oh, so that expression equals with $ \sqrt[3]{6} - 1 $ ? In final, ofc

Comment: @Bogdan15, Yes as $\sqrt[3]6>1$

Comment: Ok, and for the second expression?

Comment: @Bogdan15, Use $$\sqrt[n]a=a^{1/n}$$ and $$a^x/a^y=a^{x-y}$$ and take the LCM of the denominators of each term and add

Comment: I've solved like that but I end up in something like $ a^{\frac{2}{3}} - a^{-\frac{3}{14}} $ In my book, it is giving me just the answer, it is $ \sqrt{a} - \sqrt[21]{a^5} $

Comment: Can you help me to continue ? ( Sorry, I wanted to notify you again)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The coefficients $1,-3,3,-1$ seem to indicate a perfect cube $(a^\alpha-a^\beta)^3$. If this is true, you will find terms $a^{3\alpha}$ and $-a^{3\beta}$.